# Open Browser within an iphone app [using Phone-gap]

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, browser, cordova

I am creating an iphone app using phonegap. However, there is a requirement wherein if the user clicks an external link, it should load the content within the app. Basically it should open a browser window with only a close button, so that you can go back to what you were doing within the app. Any Idea if jquery mobile has any plugin to do so ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap has the [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) plugin.

You'll just have to attach a handler on your external links that calls `preventDefault()`, to prevent navigating away from your app, and calls `window.open` on the target URL.